# ValidatorEnable jquery function not working for people picker validator

Tags: jquery, people-picker

I have a form with a dynamically generated people picker control, that is required if the checkbox above it is selected(not required otherwise)

This is how I created the control.

```
var people = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor { ID = "PeoplePicker2" ,
                                                                  AllowEmpty = false,ValidatorEnabled = true};
```

Here is the validator

```
 divppAO2.Controls.Add(new RequiredFieldValidator
        {
            ID = "PplPkrR2fv",
            ControlToValidate = people.ID,
            ErrorMessage =
                "You must specify a value for this required field.",
            Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
            Enabled = false
        });
```

The problem comes when I try to call ValidatorEnable jquery function on this validator.

```
 checkBoxes.change(function () {
            var current = $(this),
                isChecked = current.prop('checked'),
                td = current.closest('td'),                    
                pplvalidators = td.find('span[id*="PplPkr"]');                  

            validators.each(function () {
                ValidatorEnable($(this).get(0), isChecked);
            });
```

This does seem to toggle the display of the required field message.But when I uncheck the checkbox and submit the form, form does not get submitted. It still shows the required field error message.
Where am I going wrong?
Please help.Thanks.